# Pictures in Word document do not show up in POI PicturesTable

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

This Apache POI code should (I think) produce a list of all pictures embedded in a Word document:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(in);
List<Picture> pix = doc.getPicturesTable().getAllPictures();
```

And it mostly works, except that sometimes it does not contain all pictures (just almost all of them).

Is there some other way that the picture could be stored (and some other API to get to it)? If I open the file in LibreOffice, the missing picture does not look any different (although I am not sure what properties to check) than the others.

Comment: What version of Apache POI? And if it isn't the latest, did you try upgrading?

Comment: I am using 3.8, which is the latest released version. Will try the nightly builds now.

Comment: If this is still relevant, could you share a sample document where not all pictures are contained in the result from `getAllPictures()`?